# The gradient and hessian of log sum of an inverse of the vector

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

What will be the Gradient and Hessian of the log sum of an inverse of the vector,?

For example, if $x$ is a vector, then what will be the gradient and hessian w.r.t $x$ for:
$$
\log\sum_i(\dfrac{c_i}{x_i})
$$
where $c$ is a vector of constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a colon (:) to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

and $\odot$ to denote elementwise/Hadamard multiplication 

and $\oslash$ to denote elementwise/Hadamard division.

Define a new scalar variable and its differential
$$\eqalign{
 \sigma &= 1:c\oslash x \cr &= (1\oslash x):c \cr\cr
d\sigma &= -dx\oslash (x\odot x):c \cr &=-c\oslash (x\odot x):dx
}$$
Then the function, differential, and gradient are
$$\eqalign{
 \lambda &= \log(\sigma) \implies \sigma = \exp(\lambda) \cr
\cr
d\lambda
 &= \frac{d\sigma}{\sigma} = -\frac{1}{\sigma}\,c\oslash (x\odot x):dx \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}
 &= g = -\frac{1}{\sigma}\,c\oslash (x\odot x) = -e^{-\lambda}\,c\oslash (x\odot x)\cr
}$$
If we let $$G={\rm Diag}(g),\,\,X={\rm Diag}(x)$$ 
then we can write the Hessian as 
$$H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=-(2GX^{-1}+gg^T)$$